# Is it possible to limit an FTP server connection to TLS v1.3 on Ubuntu?

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I need to test an FTP client connection to an FTP server that has only TLS v1.3 enabled. All other SSL/TLS versions must be disabled (SSLv3, TLS 1.0, 1.2, 1.3).

I tried to play with the `vsftpd` configuration file by adding the following:

```
ssl_ciphers=TLSv1.3
```

But the server does not start. If I change this line to:

```
ssl_ciphers=TLSv1.2
```

Then the server starts. Log file `/var/log/vsftpd.log` does not contain any error of the failed startup.

**Is there any option to enable TLS v1.3 in vsftpd? Is there any other FTP server that supports TLS v1.3 on Ubuntu?**

***Update 1***

I tried the following configuration on the latest Fedora, and it works. It would be nice if something similar worked on Ubuntu:

```
ssl_tlsv1=NO
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
ssl_tlsv1_1=NO
ssl_tlsv1_2=NO
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you on?  It's possible the vsftpd in the repos there is old enough that it wasn't written for TLS 1.3 protocol support.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 and lower do NOT support ssl_sslvN above v1.2.  19.04 is the one where v1.3 got added (18.04.3)

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant? [Bug #1804430: Current vsftpd builds are still lacking ssl_tlsv1_\[123\] options](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vsftpd/+bug/1804430)

Comment: I am testing on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, but I can install another if that helps